# ArcGIS 10 - mosaic: creating 4 files (rasters)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, mosaic, band

using the Mosaic to new raster tool in order to merge two satellite images, ArcGIS 10 created 4 different files: the coloured image and image1, image2 and image3 (all BW), which are, I guess, three different bands.

How to merge them all to have only one file (raster)? 
(for the purpose of storing the file in the database for the other users, to make it very simple)

Answer (score 1):

The tool you want is [Composite Bands](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000009p000000). Assuming the original was MultiBand with 6 bands, use band 1, 2 and 3 from the RGB and the other 3 bands to combine into a single 6 band image. This tool will *re-stack* the bands into a single raster, so then you can use the result image with different band combinations (like 5, 4, 2).

Comment: Thanks mate, this is what I need. In included in the processing of the composite bands tool 3 bands and not the final RGB one (3 out of 4) and an single image was created. all good. Regarding the thing why the 4 imaged were created: it happened when I clipped the raster with the shapefile! again, very odd! What about the combing the Landsat bands with this CompositeBands tool? is it possible? I tried to put B2, B3 and B4 but I am not getting automatically a real colour image,  which was expected :) is there is a good tutorial how to combine Landsat in Arc? cheers

Comment: In order to combine bands they *should* be the same cell size and extent. I haven't had to do this since stacking grids back in the 'ol days when PROJECT GRID only did one band at a time. I have however used it to tack on an Alpha (transparent) band and it worked nicely. I reckon ask another GIS.StackExchange question regarding combining LandSat images specifically.

Comment: thanks. good idea, I will ask a separate question. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just select the file geodatabase as the output of the mosaic operation and you should be good to go, be sure not to type .tif .jp etc, just leave the output file type as blan. You will always have the multiple bands in the background as they are required to properly view the image (I am assuming they are RGB bands in a 3 band standard config).

Comment: Thanks. Interesting, when creating a mosaic to the geodatabase, when I put an extension (tif) to the file name, the Arc reports the error 999999. Although it is stated in the Arc dialogue box "include name with an extension". when I put the name without an extension, it is all good. when doing the same thing to normal folder (not geodatabasse) you can put the extension and all good. probably a bug in arc or something

Comment: You got it. It is not a bug so much as just poorly documented text in yhe menus. When working in any type of ESRI geodatabase never put an extension (.jpg, .img, .shp etc.) even of the tool tells you that you must enter one.